# Import stuff from a R file

Tags: r

I'm studying R, and I was asked to use the pi2000 data set, available at the simpleR library (http://www.math.csi.cuny.edu/Statistics/R/simpleR/index.html/simpleR.R). Then I downloaded this file. How do I import it to the command line?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `source` function:

```
> source("http://www.math.csi.cuny.edu/Statistics/R/simpleR/index.html/simpleR.R")
```

You can then access the variables defined there:

```
> vacation
 [1] 23 12 10 34 25 16 27 18 28 13 14 20  8 21 23 33 30 13 16 14 38 19  6 11 15 21 10
[28] 39 42 25 12 17 19 26 20
```

for more information, type `?source` into an R terminal.

Comment: @Alex Brown thanks! is it only way to load r file in r?

Comment: @verystrongjoe, no, of course not, because R has `eval`, and it has `library`, so there are many ways to do it.  However, this is the way that R designers created for you to include one R file inline to a second.  See also `?source` to find out what options are available.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean load the function into R? If so, use `source()`:

```
source("http://www.math.csi.cuny.edu/Statistics/R/simpleR/index.html/simpleR.R")
```